# Checking multiple contains on one string

Tags: c#, string, contains

So I have a conditional that currently looks like this...

```
if (input.Contains(",") || input.Contains("/") || input.Contains(@"\") || input.Contains("."))
```

I need to add a few more characters that I want to check for and was wondering if there's a more condensed syntax to accomplish the same thing?  Something similar to SQL's IN operator?

```
if ( input IN (",", "/", @"\", ....etc )  )
```

Anybody know of any cool tricks to accomplish this without adding lots of code?

Comment: similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring

Comment: I saw that question, I was hoping I could find a easier solution since I know all the characters I'm searching for ahead of time (which I have thanks for all the answers!).

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - Adding more than 1 string to .contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212719/vb-net-adding-more-than-1-string-to-contains)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Consider using Regex (specify characters you want to check in brackets - remember that some of them must be escaped):

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[,/]");
```

or

```
new[] {",", "/"}.Any(input.Contains)
```

Answer (score 12):

How about this?

```
    if(input.IndexOfAny(new char[] { ',', '/', '\\', '.' })>=0)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Just one thing: IndexOfAny handles only single characters, it doesn't handle strings.

Comment: In the OP only single characters are checked for.

Comment: of course, that was just a side note, because IndexOf actually has an overloaded version with string.

Comment: @empi nope https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

Does this win for shortest?

```
@".,/\".Any(input.Contains)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
"asdfasdf".ContainsAny(".","/","4");

public static bool ContainsAny(this string stringToCheck, params string[] parameters)
{
    return parameters.Any(parameter => stringToCheck.Contains(parameter));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in C#. The type string does not contain a definition for "ContainsAny"

Comment: I think, he is asking you to create your own method ContainsAny(arg1, arg2). He showed that as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
If (input.IndexOfAny(new char[] { ',', '/', '\\', '.' }) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
If (input.IndexOfAny(@",/\.".ToCharArray()) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use some Linq:

```
if ( ",/\\.".ToCharArray().Any( c => input.Contains( c ) ) )
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use String.IndexOfAny -- it will scan the string for any one of a set of characters in an array:

```
if (e.Label.IndexOfAny(new char[]{',', '/', @'\', '.' /* other chars here */}) > -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An extension method could make things look clean.  Have a look at the following.

```
 public static bool ContainsChar(this string input, params char[] characters)
        {
            foreach (var character in characters)
            {
                if (input.Contains(character))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The method's parameters are variadic, so you can add as many chars as you want separated by commas.  If you're not comfortable using extension methods, modify to the following:

```
public static bool ContainsChar(string input, params char[] characters)
            {
                foreach (var character in characters)
                {
                    if (input.Contains(character))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Example usage follows:

```
string myString = "this is my string";
//extension
if (myString.ContainsChar('.', '*', '%')) //do something

//static method
if (ContainsChar(myString, '.', '*', '%')) //do something
```