# Regex to find whether XML input contains list of HTML elements

Tags: html, regex, amazon-waf

I need to write a regex pattern in AWS WAF to find whether my web request's body contains any HTML elements. Can someone please help me to write a regex for this. below are the HTML elements which I need to find and match

```
    &lt;
    &#60;
    &gt;
    &nbsp;
    &amp;
    &quot;
```

Comment: `new[] {"&lt;", "&#60;", "&gt;", "&nbsp;", "&amp;", "&quot;"}.Any(input.Contains) ` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419106/checking-multiple-contains-on-one-string#10419126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const string = "&lt;p&gt;your html belongs here&lt;/p&gt;"
string.match(/(&lt;|&#60;|&gt;|&nbsp;|&amp;|&quot;)/g) // this one will return boolean
```

Note: you should sanitize your string. I mean, you put `&lt;` to your string instead of `<`