# Is possible to add a String.contains more than one value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, contains

I want to make a control, when I create a companyId, to not permit to create id with special characters like, (&), (/), (), (ñ), ('):

```
 If txtIdCompany.Text.Contains("&") Then
   // alert error message
 End If
```

But I can't do this:

```
If txtIdCompany.Text.Contains("&", "/", "\") Then
       // alert error message
     End If
```

How can I check more than one string in the same line?

Comment: [`String.IndexOfAny()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET - Adding more than 1 string to .contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212719/vb-net-adding-more-than-1-string-to-contains)

Comment: I put this answer because I don´t find the solution in other pages yet. thanks

Comment: What about other Unicode symbols or foreign characters? You probably want to use a *whitelist* of allowed characters rather than a *blacklist* of disallowed characters.

Comment: I would suggest using a Regular Expression - similar to the one used here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788727/how-can-i-check-with-a-regex-that-a-string-contains-only-certain-allowed-charact

Comment: You could also always create your own extension method as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use collections like a `Char()` and `Enumerable.Contains`. Since `String` implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)` even this concise and efficient LINQ query works:

```
Dim disallowed = "&/\"
If disallowed.Intersect(txtIdCompany.Text).Any() Then
    ' alert error message
End If
```

here's a similar approach using `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
If txtIdCompany.Text.Any(AddressOf disallowed.Contains) Then
    ' alert error message
End If
```

a third option using [`String.IndexOfAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
If txtIdCompany.Text.IndexOfAny(disallowed.ToCharArray()) >= 0 Then
    ' alert error message
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
If txtIdCompany.Text.Contains("&") Or txtIdCompany.Text.Contains("\") Or txtIdCompany.Text.Contains("/") Then

   // alert error message

 End If
```

Comment: precisely what I wanted was not to have to do that. Because in the example I put a few characters, but I need to put all of this: (&/\ñ´'+*~$áéíóú{}[]()¿?=#@%|<>:;ç), so if I have to put: txtIdCompany.Text.Contains("&") for each one, the code will be too long. But thanks anyway.